# no instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword, ifstream

trying to do a project for class, but keep getting the error: no instance of overloaded function matches argument list relating to the implementation of the rows vector. the area that is specifically highlighted is the . operator before push_back and insert.

```
void holdLines(ifstream in, vector<string> rows) {
  string line;
  string prevLine;
  vector<string> rows;
  int lineNumber = 0;
  int vectorNumber = 0;

  while(true) {
    getline(in, line);
    if(in.fail()) {
      break;
    }
    lineNumber++;
    vectorNumber = lineNumber - 1;
    rows.push_back(lineNumber);
    rows.insert(prevLine, line);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seem you try insert an `int` into a `std::vector<std::string>`. That's unlikely to be successful.

Comment: Did you look up how to use the `push_back` and `insert` functions?

Comment: I don't think you want to `break` if `in.fail()` - I think you want to `return`.

Comment: There is also no overload of `insert()` taking two `std::string` arguments. The `position` argument to `insert()` is an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass an integer to push_back when a string is required.
It also looks like your local variable "rows" is named the same as your parameter "rows".
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is correct: there is no overload of `std::vector<std::string>::push_back` that accepts an `int`, because a `std::vector<std::string>` stores `std::string`s, not `int`s.

It's quite unclear from code alone what you are trying to do, due to the myriad mistakes, but start by replacing your `push_back` call with something sensible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method insert with two parameters of type std::string as you are trying to call

```
rows.insert(prevLine, line);
```

Also it is not clear what you are trying to do in this statement.

**Edit:** After you updated yor code nevertheless this statemenet

```
rows.push_back(lineNumber);
```

also is wrong because the `rows` is declared as a vecto of strings. It is not a vector of int and moreover class std::string does not have an appropriate constructor.

But in any case the function does not make sense because you declared a local variable with the same name as the second parameter and tried to fill this local vector that will be deleted after exiting the function

```
void holdLines(ifstream in, vector<string> rows) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  string line;
  string prevLine;
  vector<string> rows;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //..
```

I think the function should be declared either like

```
void holdLines(ifstream in, vector<string> &rows);
                                          ^^^
```

or like

```
vector<string> holdLines(ifstream in);
```

Take into account that instead of this statements

```
  while(true) {
    getline(in, line);
    if(in.fail()) {
      break;
    }
    //...
```

you could write

```
while ( getline( in, line ) )
{
    //...
```

If you need simply to fill the vector that is passed as the argument then the function can look the following way

```
void holdLines( std::ifstream &in, std::vector<std::string> &rows )
{
    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( in, line ) ) rows.push_back( line );
}
```

Comment: the idea is that I'm supposed to make a function which reads the lines in a document, and then stores the lines in a vector, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to add individual lines to the vector

Comment: the problem is she never said anything about strings having different operators than int for this context