# Can't push_back into vector - gives no overload error

Tags: c++, vector

I looked at several past questions (e.g. [no instance of overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213619/no-instance-of-overloaded-function)) but these were not relevant. I understand that there is a type mismatch but I don't understand why, with my setup, I'm getting this error.

I'm getting this error:

> no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Tp=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match) -- argument types are: (int) -- object type is: const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>

This is the code:

```
std::vector<int> sorted_edges;

...

//let's sort the edges 
for(int i = 0; i < num_nodes; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < num_nodes; ++j){
        if(graph[i][j] != INF){
            sorted_edges.push_back(i);
        }
    } 
}
```

Note: I'm not going to push an `int` into `sorted_edges` - I was testing to see whether I was incorrectly creating my edge struct or whether I was using vectors incorrectly.

Comment: Is the vector a member of a class and the code you've shown in a const member function?  A [mcve] would allow for a real answer that takes your real code into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the error you get:

> ... the object has ***type qualifiers*** that prevent a match -- argument types are: (int) -- object type is: ***const*** std::vector.

First, you should check the code you've posted is correct - you state it's a non-const but the error clearly states otherwise, though you *may* be passing it to a function as a const ref - that's one possibility.

In any case, you cannot `push_back` into a `const vector` since it's, well, `const` :-)

You can see that with the following code:

```
#include <vector>
int main() { XYZZY std::vector<int> x; x.push_back(42); }
```

When you compile with `-DXYZZY=` (so the `XYZZY` effectively disappears), it compiles okay. With `-DXYZZY=const` however, you get an error:

```
qq.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
qq.cpp:2:54: error: passing ‘const std::vector<int>’ as ‘this’
    argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    int main() { XYZZY std::vector<int> x; x.push_back(42); }
                                                         ^
```

Comment: Ah I see, not sure why, but initializing the vector in the function that I use it in seems to have solved the problem. I'm guessing there's a problem with how I set up the class.

Comment: @AnkilP, there is no problem in *initialising* a `const` variable, otherwise `const double pi = 2.718281828459;` wouldn't work :-) So, if that works for you, that's fine. If you ever need to *change* the value, you'll need to figure out why it's `const` and fix that.

Comment: @AnkilP well if you initialize your class as `const` and `sorted_edges` is a member of that class you can for sure not modify it.